# Enum factory using Java 8 supplier

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, factory, supplier

I am trying to create objects (implement factory pattern) using Java 8 lambda and `Supplier` interface.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    FactoryEnum.getEnumByClassName("CLASS_A").getSupplier().execute();
    FactoryEnum.getEnumByClassName("CLASS_B").getSupplier().execute();
  }
```

---

```
enum FactoryEnum {

  CLASS_A(() -> A::new),

  CLASS_B(() -> B::new);

  private final Supplier<IConverter> supplier;

  FactoryEnum(final Supplier<IConverter> supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  public static FactoryEnum getEnumByClassName(final String className) {
    return FactoryEnum.valueOf(className);
  }

  public IConverter getSupplier() {
    return supplier.get();
  }
}
```

---

```
interface IConverter {

  void execute();
}
```

---

```
class A implements IConverter {

  @Override
  public void execute() {

    System.out.println("Inside A"); //$NON-NLS-1$
  }

}
```

---

```
class B implements IConverter {

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    System.out.println("Inside B");
  }

}
```

---

When I call `FactoryEnum.getEnumByClassName("CLASS_A").getSupplier().execute()` I was expecting this to return an newly created Object of Class A and `FactoryEnum.getEnumByClassName("CLASS_A").getSupplier().execute()` and this to return newly created object of Class B. While it is returning me an Lambda. Why is it returning lambda rather then an Object of `IConverter`. And how I can get that?

Comment: Question got closed before I could submit my answer. While it *is* a typo, I think an explanation of *why* it's a typo might be useful. Here it is https://pastebin.com/Q6bxCZhg

Comment: There is, by the way, no sense in creating an additional method `getEnumByClassName` that does the same as the already existing `valueOf` method, especially when its only feature, the distinct name, is misleading, as the argument is *not* a class name.

Comment: @Michael : Thanks for your help. I wrote this intentionally, because Actually I got the interpretation of A::new to new A(), while it is () -> {new A()}.

Comment: @Holger Yes, totally make sense. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CLASS_A(() -> A::new)
```

means

```
CLASS_A(() -> { return A::new; })
```

which means

```
CLASS_A(() -> { return () -> { new A(); }; })
```

which isn't what you were trying to convey.

Try

```
CLASS_A(A::new)
```

Comment: or `CLASS_A(() -> new A())` :)